# Whats wrong in preg_match("/\<script\>

Tags: php, preg-match

i want to find anything between

```
"<script> ytplayer" and "ytplayer.config.loaded" .
```

my code shown in following:

```
preg_match("/\<script\>var\s+ytplayer.+?ytplayer\.config\.loaded/", 

$file_contents, $videosource);
```

I tried to fix it but it did not.

Comment: you want something after `<script> ytplayer`, your regex says `\<script\>var\s+`.

Comment: Out of curiosity... You are escaping `<` and `>`, assuming they are special chars. What meaning do you think they have when not escaped?

Comment: ok i want to find between     <script>var ytplayer and      ytplayer.config.loaded

Answer (score 1):

Make a captur group:

```
preg_match("/\<script\>var\s+ytplayer(.+?)ytplayer\.config\.loaded/", $file_contents, $videosource);
//           note the parens      ___^ __^
```

The capture will be in `$videosource[1]`

Answer (score 0):

It should be...

```
preg_match("/\\<script\\> ytplayer(.+)ytplayer\\.config\\.loaded/", $file_contents, $videosource);
```

Notice the double escapes.  You have to use two backslashes because `"\<"` means the same as `<` whereas `"\\<"` is the same as `\<`.  Also as M42 pointed out, you should have a grouping around the middle stuff.  This makes the middle stuff available in `$videosource[1]`.

If you want the match to be case-insensitive, you can use this

```
preg_match("/\\<script\\> ytplayer(.+)ytplayer\\.config\\.loaded/i", $file_contents, $videosource);
```

The `i` at the end of the regex makes it case-insensitive.

Comment: Why to escape `<` at all? It doesn't have any special meaning in that context in regexp, does it?

Answer (score 0):

RegEx is literal unless you're using wildcards. It might be easier to only use the parts that are necessary. For this you can use lookarounds with atomic grouping.

```
$pattern = "!(?<=(ytplayer)).*(?=(ytplayer))!";
preg_match($pattern,$file_contents,$matches);

$videosource = $matches[0];
```